My random string picker is choosing a different string on server side and client side
I have this component in Next.js (v14.2.1) which, essentially, all it does is to pick a random string while i fetch some data. However, i've been trying to persist the same string on server and client side without any luck.
I honestly don't know what else to do.
Here's my current code:
const RandomLoadingText = () => {
  const possibleLoadingTexts = [
    "Asking Chat-GPT for a quote...",
    "Not loading...",
    "Tickling the Servers for Answers...",
    "Convincing the Hamsters to Run Faster...",
    "Summoning digital elves to fetch a witty quote...",
  ];

  const getRandomLoadingText = () => {
    const randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * possibleLoadingTexts.length);
    return possibleLoadingTexts[randomIndex] as never;
  };

  const [loadingText] = useState(getRandomLoadingText)

  return (
    <div>
      <span className={`${lobster.className} text-lg`}>"</span>
      {loadingText}
      <span className={`${lobster.className} text-lg`}>"</span>
    </div>
  );
};

export default RandomLoadingText;

I simply tried picking a random string in an array to display while i fetch some data, but the string changes between SSR and CSR causing Hydration errors.

Have you tried not using state?

I did but that's not working either.

I can think of 2 options to solve this:

Generate the random index from RSC and pass to the client component via props.
use useEffect and setState only once there once initialized. Initial state maybe empty string


I created a server component that defines the SSR string, however, it's still being rendered twice (Server side and Client side)

No, you don't define the index again in client, as I mention in point 1. you pass the index to client, client use this index to get the string data, then this will solve the random index. Only regenerate index after mounting done, will not cause SSR issue, this solves your issue IMO

I think your useState hook doesn't write properly, const [loadingText] = useState(getRandomLoadingText) it should const [loadingText, setLoadingText] = useState()
also, try to use useEffect and use setLoadingText while fetching data

I tried this, and it kinda works. However, the server side string is undefined :(

So it starts with an empty string and then picks a string.
